# Button action not being called in new view controller

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have a table view as my RootViewController and push another one on a button press with this code.

```
[[self navigationController] pushViewController:aboutVC animated:YES];
```

My problem is that my button's actions are not called when they are pressed.  I have checked almost everything that I can think of and I am pretty sure that there is a view overtop of my button that is intercepting the user interaction.  I have nothing else other than the button and its action coded in my new view controller.  I am using a custom cell, but there is nothing in it yet.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[CustomCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
    cell.userInteractionEnabled = NO;

    //ADD BUTTONS
    UIButton *redButton = [[UIButton alloc] init];
    redButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0/255 green:0.0/255 blue:0.0/255 alpha:1.00];
    [redButton addTarget:self action:@selector(redButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    redButton.frame = CGRectMake(9, 44, 40, 39);

    [cell addSubview:redButton];

    [redButton release];
    return cell;
}


- (void)redButton:(id)sender
{
    //Button action will go here
}
```

any ideas on what i might be doing wrong?

Comment: you set  cell.userInteractionEnabled = YES; then action will call,and add button like this [cell.contentView addSubview:redButton];

Comment: @Narayana - I was just about to answer but your comment came in first.  Can you post as answer?

Comment: I tried this with no luck.  as I understand it, the cell does not need to have user interaction enabled because the button user interaction is a separate setting.  This is how I did it in my RootViewController and it works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
cell.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
[cell addSubview:redButton];
```

> Replace above lines with below 2 lines of code it will work

```
cell.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
[cell.contentView addSubview:redButton];
```

Comment: +1 - also note that UITableViewCell inherits from UIView which is what offers userInteractionEnabled

Comment: I have tried this and it still does not work. The button is displaying, but not being called.  Maybe it was not clear, but I am adding the button in the cellForRowAtIndexPath, not in the CustomCell class, if that somehow makes a difference.

Comment: you changed this line [cell.contentView addSubview:redButton];

Comment: I did, Im not sure if it means anything, but when I select a cell, the cell highlight color overlaps my button.  I dont think this is supposed to happen normally.

Comment: I have identified the pronlem, although I dont know how to fix it.  The problem is caused from using a custom cell.  I have nothing in my custom cell file, but if i use it, the button does not register if i set it below 44 pixels.  even if the 44px threshold goes through the button, it works above 44px but not below.  any ideas on how to fix?

Comment: you have - (void)layoutSubviews method in custom cell class

Comment: how do i avoid the 44px problem in that case?

Comment: self.contentView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 121);  in layoutSubviews solved my problem.